# Using swiftmailer and sending attachments

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to modify a script to send a email with an attachment. It works right now but all the fields are required and I was wondering what I am missing to make it so the fields are not required.

```
<?php
if (($_POST)) {

$success = $error = false;

$post = new stdClass;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
    $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));

    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

    ob_start();
    require_once($dir.'/html.php');
    $html_message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');

    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport());

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                   ->setSubject('Imperial Order') // Message subject
                   ->setTo(array($post->email => $post->name, 'ehilse@paifashion.com' => 'Janet McCauley')) // Array of people to send to
                   ->setFrom(array('noreply@paifashion.com' => 'Imperial Order'))
                   ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html') // Attach that HTML message from earlier
                   ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])->setFilename($_FILES['attachment']['name']));

    // Send the email, and show user message
    if ($mailer->send($message))
        $success = true;
    else
        $error = true;      
}
?>
```

I believe it has something to do with the foreach but if I try taking it out it breaks the whole code. If anyone can help that would be great. The reason I am taking out the validation is because i'm wanting to do it on the client side instead of server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the for each but then you'll have to request each posted field individually and process/validate them one at a time instead of in a loop as the loop is pulling all the post vars to local vars.

Also you don't need to require the swift mailer includes etc inside of the loop they can be moved outside of the loop as can the $mailer = new transport start line that can all go outside of the loop

**EDIT WITH EXAMPLE**

```
if (isset($_POST)) { //BAD BAD BAD way of checking there's better ways

$success = $error = false;

$input1 = $_POST['input1'];
$input2 = $_POST['input2'];
$input3 = $_POST['input3'];
$input4 = $_POST['input4'];

    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    // THIS BIT IS RETARDED BUT LEAVING IT IN FOR NOW
    ob_start();
    require_once($dir.'/html.php');
    $html_message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    // END RETARDED BIT
    require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');
    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport());
    if (isset($_FILES) && strlen($_FILES['attachment']['name']) > 0) { //here we're checking that there is attachments if there are then we're going to do the attach sw code
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                   ->setSubject('Imperial Order') // Message subject
                   ->setTo(array($input1 => $input2, 'ehilse@paifashion.com' => 'Janet McCauley')) // Array of people to send to
                   ->setFrom(array('noreply@paifashion.com' => 'Imperial Order'))
                   ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html') // Attach that HTML message from earlier
                   ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])->setFilename($_FILES['attachment']['name']));
    } else {
        //non attach sw code
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                   ->setSubject('Imperial Order') // Message subject
                   ->setTo(array($input1 => $input2, 'ehilse@paifashion.com' => 'Janet McCauley')) // Array of people to send to
                   ->setFrom(array('noreply@paifashion.com' => 'Imperial Order'))
                   ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html') // Attach that HTML message from earlier
    }
    //there's better ways of doing the above but as an example this will suffice.
    // Send the email, and show user message
    if ($mailer->send($message)) {
        $success = true;
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: if I wanted to keep the loop to process them but not validate them how would I do that.

Comment: The problem is that `foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)` loops through all POST'd inputs.  So leaving one blank will create a blank value/entry in your array which is whats breaking your send.  You could kinda get around it by leaving it as is but putting an `if (strlen($post->email)>0 && strlen($post->name)>0) { //code here }` around your $message block and the if statement below it.  That way it'd only attempt to send the mail if there were actually values in the input fields.

Comment: Could you tell me how to process each field then? I'm not exactly sure how I would do that... The main problem I am having is they dont want the upload field to be required.

Comment: added code example now it'll only work if there's only a single input for name/email address if you have multiple then you'll need to construct a recipient array before hand and push that to the sw object but thats like 2 lines of code.

Comment: when I try that it breaks the code...at first I thought it was missing a semi colon at the end of the setBody on the else statement but that didn't change anything...

Comment: I did miss the ; at the end of the ->setBody which will have broke it but I rushed it so I probably missed something else else where a }{ or () or something . The concept is right though so you can use it as a basis to improve/fix upon

Comment: Okay... well I figured out what was causing it but now when it loads it instantly sends the email. Then after it loads I try filling it out and its not passing the variables through...

Comment: thats to do with the very first line! as i say in the code `if (isset($_POST)) { //BAD BAD BAD way of checking there's better ways` a better way is putting a hidden field in your form and checking that the value of the hidden field `isset()` and that it matches a fixed string so i use for example `<input type="hidde" name="action" id="action" value="dosomething" />` then my check is `if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="dosomething") {`

Comment: Okay that makes sense but what would be causing the input to not pass through? I'm just doing echo in the html.php document.

Comment: not entirely sure all I can assume is your input vars aren't being passed through to your html template properly or you may need to adjust html.php to allow for non loops as it may be looking for $key $var where its now $input1 $input2 etc.